# Executing a node command in google script

Tags: node.js, http

How do we make google scripts execute a node js in the index js of another website when you execute an HTTP request?

Ex:

```
function logProductInfo() {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://testsite.com/");
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

testsite.com contains a node js command. It gets executed when I use

```
node index.js
```

in the command prompt in my local, but I can't seem to do it online.

Comment: You'd have to run the http server using node. You don't route traffic to node, like you do for php. See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html.